# Nginx configuration like Synology reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, config, synology

I am trying configuring nginx (based on bitname/nginx:latest) as equivalent of Synology reverse proxy. This is due to missing wild-card redirect at Synology. While doing so, I face many issues; therfore I am requesting help for proper nginx configuration.

**requirements**

- HTTPS upgrade
- Redirect any wild-card subdomain (443) to a port 30'000
- Hide the redirect port from user visibility
- WebSockets must be supported (At Synology following header: Upgrade $http_upgrade AND Connection $connection_upgrade)

**Example**

- Browser calls http://app1.my-example.com/
- re-direct to http**s**://app1.my-example.com:30000/
- Browser displays: https://app1.my-example.com/, resolving via Port 30000

**Current Code (not working so far)**

```
# Test
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.my\-example.com$;
    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/yourapp_access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/yourapp_error.log;
 
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
 
        proxy_pass https://$host:30000$request_uri/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

# Catch malicious requests
server {
   listen 8080 default_server;
   listen [::]:8080 default_server;
   server_name _;
 
   return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my issue and would like to share the results. The only thing I do not get is, why redirect.my-example is OK as proxy_pass. It would hit the very same route (probably an endless-loop). Feedback/Improvement would be apreciated!

```
# custom code for hop by hop headers
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
 
# Upgrade connection
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;
    server_name _;
    
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
 
# Redirect Subdomains (incl. Web-Socket)
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate      /certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /certs/server.key;
    
    server_name my-example.de portal.my-example.de;
    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/yourapp_access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/yourapp_error.log;
 
    location / {
        proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header     HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header     X-NginX-Proxy true;
 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
 
        proxy_pass https://redirect.my-example.de:30000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
# Catch malicious requests
server {
   listen 8443 default_server;
   listen [::]:8443 default_server;
   
   ssl_certificate      /certs/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  /certs/server.key;
   
   server_name _;
 
   return 444;
}
```